# How to see date of folder sharing in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, sharing

How do I see the date of when I shared a folder in Google Drive.

Answer (score 2):

1. Log in to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com)
2. In the toolbar click the "Details and Activity" button (looks like an 'i' in a circle). This should open the activity pane.
3. You can now see all your activities on Drive, including the date in which you shared items.